# How to setup a work -> home -> internet http tunneling service

Tags: proxy, firewall, http, tunnel, privacy

I want to know which program is recommended in order to setup such as scenario, i.e. accessing the Internet from work or other places where traffic is monitored by installing a HTTP tunneling service in a home computer.

**EDIT:** Is it possible to achieve the same by installing a home proxy?

Comment: I'd be very interested in this, too, my college blocks non port-80 ports. A bugger for web development, no ftp!

Comment: You might also want to make sure it's all right with your superiors.  You don't give any details except that traffic is monitored.  If it turns out that this is not acceptable at work, the fact that you went to extra effort to do this will not be a point in your favor.

Comment: yes i am aware of the implications David

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Install [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx) on your home and work computers.
- Install [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org) on your home computer and configure it to bind to the Hamachi adapter.
- Configure your web browser at work to use your home Hamachi/Privoxy proxy (point it at your home computer's Hamachi address, `5.*.*.*`, port 8118).

Your home computer will then be your gateway to the internet rather than some server at work.  There is a downside to this and that is your web surfing is most likely to slow down considerably because you'll be at the mercy of your home connection's upstream bandwidth.  For instance, my DSL connection at home is 12Mbps down, but only 768Kbps up.  So, I'm limited to downloading at 768Kbps if I use my home proxy as opposed to our work connection which is much faster.  You can always use another browser (or use Firefox and [FoxyProxy](http://foxyproxy.mozdev.org) to makes toggling the proxy easy) when you need more bandwidth, say for a work-related download.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a home proxy - but I would recommend a ssh connection to the proxy from the outside so that no-one else can easily use your very own proxy.
For the SSH side I would use putty via a memory stick.
Also an alternative would be l[logmein](https://secure.logmein.com/US/home.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

What about [anonymouse](http://anonymouse.org/)? That will let you view websites via a proxy.

I used to use it at Uni to check gaming forums as those were blocked by the firewall, but it all depends on how secure their internet usage is

Comment: work proxies generally ban those sites as well